# Matrix $B$ that satisfies $B\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{x}-(\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{x})\mathbf{v}$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $B \in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ satisfy the following relation $$B\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{x}-(\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{x})\mathbf{v}$$ where $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{v}\in \mathbb{R}^n$.
>   The entries of $B$ are given by $(B\mathbf{e}_j)_i$ for all $i,j=1,...,n.$ Calculate $B_{ij}$.

This is my reasoning so far: $$\sum_{j=1}^{n}\begin{pmatrix}B_{1j} \\ \vdots \\ B_{nj}\end{pmatrix} x_j = \sum_{j=1}^{n}x_j\mathbf{e}_j-\left( \sum_{j=1}^{n}x_jv_j \right) \left( \sum_{j=1}^{n}v_j\mathbf{e}_j \right) \\ \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}B_{ij}x_j\mathbf{e_i} = \sum_{j=1}^{n}x_j\mathbf{e}_j - \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_jv_jv_i\mathbf{e}_i \\ x_j\sum_{i=1}^nB_{ij}\mathbf{e}_i=x_j\mathbf{e}_j-x_jv_j\sum_{i=1}^{n}v_i\mathbf{e}_i$$
I'm not sure what to do from here, and even whether the above is valid. I haven't used the fact that $B_{ij}=(B\mathbf{e}_j)_i$, since it's not clear to me what that actually means. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: What is fixed, and what is a variable here? If $\textbf x$ is fixed, and if it's $0$, then you can't say anything about the entries of $B$. I mean you need to learn to use "for some ..." and "for every ..." to make statements clear.

Comment: $B_{ij}=(B\mathbf{e}_j)_i$ is not something deep you're going to use, it's a notation to avoid writing $(B\mathbf{e}_j)_i$ all the time.

Comment: $n \times n = n^2$ unknowns in $n$ equations ...

Comment: Note that $B_{i,j}=e_j\cdot Be_i=e_j\cdot e_i-(v\cdot e_i)(e_j\cdot v)$. Therefore $B=I-vv^T$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint : You can rewrite the expression as
\begin{align*}
&B\mathbf x=\mathbf x-(\mathbf v\cdot \mathbf x)\mathbf v\\
\Leftrightarrow&B\mathbf x=\mathbf x-\mathbf v (\mathbf v^T \mathbf x)\\
\Leftrightarrow& B\mathbf x=(I-\mathbf v \mathbf v^T) \mathbf x\\
\end{align*}

Comment: and then what happens ?

Comment: Not sure, it depends on the question. If the equality is satisfied for all $\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf v$ is fixed, then $B=I-\mathbf v\mathbf v^T$

Comment: that's one choice yes.

Comment: @P.Quinton that is the case, yes. I should have stated that in the question

Comment: So, if $B=I-\mathbf{v}\mathbf{v}^T$, can I then write $B_{ij}=\delta_{ij}-v_iv_j$?

Comment: Yes (filling for characters)

Answer (score 1):

Building up on what @P.Quinton wrote.

$$B\mathbf x=(I-\mathbf v \mathbf v^T) \mathbf x$$
means that we have infinitely many solutions of the form
$$B = I-\mathbf v \mathbf v^T + P_x^{\perp}$$
where $P_x^{\perp}$ is a matrix that has $x$ as zero eigenvector, that is $P_x^{\perp} x = 0$. One choice is the projector matrix that projects onto the nullspace of $x$,
$$P_x^{\perp} - I - \frac{1}{x^T x}xx^T$$